# lines that only intersect a curve at 2 points

Tags: linear-algebra

I have some data points that define a curve and what i need to find is the slope of the lines definedby
line 1 = p1&p2
line 2 = p1&p3
line 3 = p1&p4
.
.
.
line29= p1&p30
line30= p2&p3
line31= p2&p4

linexxx = p29&p30 being the last

and I as I go i need to determine if the lines above  *ONLY* have 2 points in common with the curve?
image below the blue line is valid the green isnt how can I tell this?

[image]

point 1     0.128250002 6.235036978 
point 2     0.197718753 6.239911671 
point 3     0.281734379 6.22376425  
point 4     0.336656255 6.233513636 
point 5     0.347343755 6.20761683  
point 6     0.472625007 6.238083661 
point 7     0.491625008 6.205484151 
point 8     0.553968759 6.244786364 
point 9     0.601765634 6.200609458 
point 10    0.740703137 6.243263022 
point 11    0.797703137 6.225287592 
point 12    0.927140639 6.245091032 
point 13    1.078546892 6.239911671 
point 14    1.159890643 6.249661057 
point 15    1.291703145 6.238997666 
point 16    1.404812522 6.262457126 
point 17    1.506937524 6.248747052 
point 18    1.6057969   6.213405528 
point 19    1.684765651 6.243263022 
point 20    1.770859403 6.235341646 
point 21    1.94037503  6.247833047 
point 22    2.059125032 3.903410396 
point 23    2.189453159 3.681916534 
point 24    2.330468786 4.359194189 
point 25    2.398453162 6.237169656 
point 26    2.55728129  6.279213883 
point 27    2.692656292 6.248747052 
point 28    2.844359419 6.254840418 
point 29    2.992203172 6.264589804 
point 30    3.167062549 6.243263022

Comment: See [Point-Slope Equation of a Line](http://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/line-equation-point-slope.html) for helpful illustrations and formulas. Once you have equation of a line, say between points $m$ and $n$, plug $x$-coordinates of points between $m$ in $n$ in the line equation, and subtract the results from your $y$-values. If all these differences have the same sign (either all positive or all negative), the line is valid (does not cross the curve).